# Sort Arrays By Their Length

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer

I have the following arrays:

http://jsfiddle.net/3NZsK/

I need to sort the arrays by their length.

How to find out which one is the largest, the second largest, the third largest, and the least array?

For example, I have the following dummy function, that can get us the second largest array:

http://jsfiddle.net/WPRYf/

What is the above dummy function algorithm?

Thank you in advance

Comment: sorry, what? you mean you want to sort the arrays by their length?

Comment: I want to find out which one is the largest, the second largest, the third largest and the smallest in quantity. I need to assign them into above variables (please see my explanation)

Comment: I think when @gexicide said "What?" he meant that your explanation doesn't make a lot of sense, and he would like you to clarify it.

Comment: Ok. Yes, I want to sort the arrays by their length. How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried with length? Determine each array length like this: example: arr_a.length will give the length of the array.

Comment: I think he wants to find the largest number, the third largest number, and the lowest number in an array. Maybe. He hasn't given enough details

Comment: Yes. I can only get the largest and the smallest array. I need to get the second and the third

Comment: @David: No, I want to get the largest, the smallest, the second largest, and the third largest arrays (by their length)

Comment: In that case the second fiddle example is wrong.

Comment: What do you want to do with that information? What do you do if two arrays have the same, largest length? Same question for smallest length, and for third largest.

Comment: If two arrays have the same length, then both arrays should have the same position. For example, if two arrays have the largest length, they are number 1

Comment: Is this limited to 4 arrays? Do you have an array of arrays? How do you want the result to be formated? (array, collection). Assigning each array to a variable contradicts what you are saying in the previous comment. Get your thoughts together and ask properly.

Comment: @Angel: I'm sorry for being unclear. Assigning each array to a variable is just one example of the result might be. My answers: Yes this is limited to 4 arrays. I don't have array of arrays. To make it easier, I want to create function that can return me an array with the second largest length. Hopefully the following example will make it clear: http://jsfiddle.net/WPRYf/

Comment: Ok, was a little late, I see one answer by Yoshi that might help you with what you need.

Comment: @Angel: Yes it is. Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var
  a = ["a", "a"];
  b = ["b", "b", "b", "b"],
  c = ["c", "c", "c"],
  d = ["d"],
  container = [a, b, c, d];

​container.sort(function (a, b) {
  return b.length - a.length;
});

console.log(container);
```

`container` will be sorted from longest (most elements) to shortest (least number of elements). Access it as:

```
container[0] // longest
container[1] // 2nd longest
// ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pSRVq/

Answer (score 1):

You can find the length of the array using the length method and then sort these according to their values to find the largest, second largest array.